# How can I find an instance of a whole word in Java (Android)? for user tagging on a social media app

Tags: java, android, pattern-matching

I'm building a social media app and I want to add the "tagging" functionality. My initial thought was to look for an instance of a whole word beginning with @. This is what I've got so far.

```
String text = "@martin I will come and meet you at the woods 123@martin @ martin";

List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
tokens.add("@martin"); // martin should be an string arbitrary

String patternString = "\\b(" + StringUtils.join(tokens, "|") + ")\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

It should print out `@martin` but not `123@martin`, `@` or `@ martin`, etc.

Am I close to a solution here, and is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String text = "@martin I will come and meet you at the woods 123@martin @ martin";

String patternString = "(^|\\W)(@\\w+?)(\\W|$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
}
```

Comment: I think the `tokens` list was needed to determine whether a tag was valid or not. This regex will allow any word with an `@` to be used as a tag, even for some username that doesn't exist

Comment: Just do something like this:

    `List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();
    tokens.add("@martin");

    String patternString ="(^|\\W)(" + StringUtils.join(tokens, "|") + ")(\\W|$)";`

Comment: Without `Pattern.quote`, there may be trouble with this approach. Also, consecutive matches won't be found (`@martin,@joe @kate`).

Comment: We can use lookbehind and lookahead: `(?<=(^|\\W))(@\\w+?)(?=(\\W|$))` for consecutive matches.